# Object Detection with Red Laser

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, detection, matlab-guide

I want to do object detection with a laser in matlab. When I point the laser at an object, I can detect that object; however, because the color of my laser is red, when the laser is pointed at a red object, I can not detect that object.

Here is my process: First, I separate red objects using different methods. If the R value of an object equals 255, I say this is laser the laser. However, if the R value of another object equals 255 (i.e., the object is red), I can not detect laser (because they are the same color). How can I do?

Comment: Are you asking how to detect a red spot, on a red background?

Answer (score 2):

Use two lasers of different colors. For example, if you have a red and blue laser, the red laser will show up on blue objects and the blue laser on red objects.

If you're bent on using a single laser, you could check the intensity of the laser point, but this will be much more difficult in real environments.